# react-native-camera | ios10 - app crash when <Camera/> is rendered

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

i have a problem with app. problem does not appear in ios < 10. very similar to existing issue on github : https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/386.

steps taken:
descriptions of mic, camera are filled

xcode shows this on very end:

[self.session commitConfiguration]; Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50)

any help or hints ?

react-native 0.36, react-native-camera 0.38

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I had this same issue using ios 10

I had to delete my reference to react native camera and npm using this:

`npm i react-native-camera@next --save`

This seemed to clear it up after including it in xcode library and linking in binary under project build phase. Hope this works for you